# Select column with Case and using WHERE on that column

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a little complicated but I simplified it as much as I can. I have a contacts table that contains first name last name, etc. It also contains 2 columns indicating the group (src) the contact is associated with and it's id in that group (uID). I'm trying to do a contact search. So if I'm looking for mike, it's simple enough

```
... WHERE fname LIKE '%mik%'.
```

That returns all mikes. What I'm trying to do now is do a search based on the group or name. So if I want all the contacts associated with groupA; I would go

```
.. WHERE fname LIKE '%mik%' OR code LIKE '%groupA%'.
```

Unfortunately this returns an error

> 'invalid column name code'.

Here's what my actual SQL looks like:

```
SELECT 
    c.contactID, 
    CASE c.src 
     WHEN 0 THEN (SELECT tbl.code FROM CSA.dbo.Clients tbl WHERE clientID=c.uID)
     WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT tbl.scac FROM CSA.dbo.Carriers tbl WHERE carrierID=c.uID)
     WHEN 2 THEN (SELECT tbl.code FROM codeBase tbl WHERE cID=c.uID) 
    END as code,
    fName+' '+lname, 
    cType 

FROM contacts c 

WHERE fname LIKE '%mi%' OR code LIKE '%mi%'
```

So as you can see I'm doing the case to return the code based on what group and id they have. How do I search on that code column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT 
    c.contactID, 
    CASE c.src 
     WHEN 0 THEN (SELECT tbl.code FROM CSA.dbo.Clients tbl WHERE clientID=c.uID)
     WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT tbl.scac FROM CSA.dbo.Carriers tbl WHERE carrierID=c.uID)
     WHEN 2 THEN (SELECT tbl.code FROM codeBase tbl WHERE cID=c.uID) 
    END as code,
    fName+' '+lname, 
    cType 

FROM contacts c 

WHERE fname LIKE '%mi%' OR 
    CASE c.src 
     WHEN 0 THEN (SELECT tbl.code FROM CSA.dbo.Clients tbl WHERE clientID=c.uID)
     WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT tbl.scac FROM CSA.dbo.Carriers tbl WHERE carrierID=c.uID)
     WHEN 2 THEN (SELECT tbl.code FROM codeBase tbl WHERE cID=c.uID) 
    END LIKE '%mi%'
```

Alternatively use a CTE:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
        c.contactID, 
        CASE c.src 
         WHEN 0 THEN (SELECT tbl.code FROM CSA.dbo.Clients tbl WHERE clientID=c.uID)
         WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT tbl.scac FROM CSA.dbo.Carriers tbl WHERE carrierID=c.uID)
         WHEN 2 THEN (SELECT tbl.code FROM codeBase tbl WHERE cID=c.uID) 
        END as code,
        fName+' '+lname as fullname,
        fname, 
        cType 

    FROM contacts c 
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE fname like '%mi%' or code like '%mi%'
```

Comment: That worked awesome. It looks almost exactly what i put, why does it work when it's in that CTE thing, and not without it?

Comment: The WHERE clause of the SELECT statement happens before the SELECT part, therefore the field 'code' doesn't exist at the point you are trying to use it in the WHERE. My first statement repeats the CASE in the WHERE clause so works. The CTE is like a virtual table, it functions like a subselect so that the code column exists when you wish to filter on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [common table expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to get your result including the `code` column and then filter on it.

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT 
    c.contactID, 
    CASE c.src 
     WHEN 0 THEN (SELECT tbl.code FROM CSA.dbo.Clients tbl WHERE clientID=c.uID)
     WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT tbl.scac FROM CSA.dbo.Carriers tbl WHERE carrierID=c.uID)
     WHEN 2 THEN (SELECT tbl.code FROM codeBase tbl WHERE cID=c.uID) 
    END as code,
    fName+' '+lname AS fullname, 
    fName,
    cType 

  FROM contacts c
)
SELECT contactID, code, fullname, cType FROM CTE
WHERE fname LIKE '%mi%' OR code LIKE '%mi%'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three approaches to this:

- **Repeating the `CASE` inside `WHERE`** - this is not recommended, because you repeat a lot of code between the `SELECT` and `WHERE`
- **Wrap the query into a `SELECT *`, and use its columns in the outer `WHERE`** - this approach is reasonably portable
- **Use [Common Table Expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)** - this approach is similar to the one above, but it leads to a somewhat cleaner query.